# MVVM: How to bind to a ListBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

As you will notice I'm new to WPF-MVVM.

I'm trying to build a simple app to understand the basics. I read almost all the questions that's been asked here and some on other sites. I can't seem to wrap my mind around it with the examples/answers given.

First the scenario:

I want to get information from a remote computer using WMI.

On my XAML I have two textboxes for computer name and the WMI_Class(**For testing purposes I was using the Win32_OperatingSystem formated but would want this be optional eventually with different classes**.

In my project I have the following folders:
Views
Models
ViewModel

I was able to get all the info I want without the MVVM part. Any help would be appreciated. My codes are below for this simple app.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="RemoteComputerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RemoteComputerTest"
    xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:RemoteComputerTest.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="LightGray">
        <Label Content="Computer Name" />
        <TextBox x:Name="ComputerName" Width="100" Height="30" />
        <Label Content="Class Name" />
    <TextBox x:Name="ClassName"
                 Width="100"
                 Height="30" 
             Margin="0,10,0,0"/>

        <Button x:Name="Submit"
                Height="40"
                Width="60"
                Margin="0,20,0,0"
                Content="Submit"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Name="ListBox" Background="LightBlue">

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I've been playing around so much with the code that it may not make sense anymore

**Model**

```
namespace RemoteComputerTest.Model
{
   public class sysInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string _computerName;

    public string ComputerName
    {
        get { return _computerName; }
        set {_computerName = value; }
    }

    private string _className;

    public string ClassName
    {
        get { return _className; }
        set { _className = value; }
    }


    StringBuilder _result = new StringBuilder();

    public StringBuilder RemoteComputerInfoCustomized(string ComputerName)
    {

        _result.Clear();

        try
        {
            ManagementScope ManagementScope1 = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", ComputerName));
            ManagementScope1.Connect();
            ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementPath managementPath1 = new ManagementPath(ClassName);
            ManagementClass ManagementClass1 = new ManagementClass(ManagementScope1, managementPath1, objectGetOptions);


            foreach (ManagementObject ManagementObject1 in ManagementClass1.GetInstances())
            {
                // Display the remote computer information
                this._result.Append(string.Format("Computer Name : {0}", ManagementObject1["csname"]));
                this._result.Append(string.Format("Windows Directory : {0}", ManagementObject1["WindowsDirectory"]));
                this._result.Append(string.Format("Operating System: {0}", ManagementObject1["Caption"]));
                this._result.Append(string.Format("Version: {0}", ManagementObject1["Version"]));
                this._result.Append(string.Format("Manufacturer : {0}", ManagementObject1["Manufacturer"]));
                this._result.Append(string.Format("Latest bootup time : {0}", ManagementObject1["LastBootUpTime"]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _result.Append(string.Format("Can't Connect to Computer: {0}\n{1}", ComputerName, ex.Message));
        }

        return _result;
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler ph = PropertyChanged;
        if (ph != null)
            ph(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
    }
}
```

As far as the ViewModel, I really don't know what or how to call and write it to the listbox in the xaml. Code might be a mess and I apologize been working on this for few days not and gotten nowhere!

**ViewModel**

```
namespace RemoteComputerTest.ViewModels
{
   public class sysInfoVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    private sysInfo _getremotecomputer;
    public StringBuilder results;

   //giving error "must have a return type 
   public RemoteComputerVM(string compName, StringBuilder RST ) 
    {
        _result = RST;
        _getremotecomputer = new sysInfo();
        _getremotecomputer.ComputerName = "TEST-DESKTOP";

        return _results; //error here "because viewmodel returns void keyword must not be followed with an object. Which I don't have void? 


    }


    private StringBuilder Results;

    public StringBuilder _results
    {
        get { return Results; }
        set { _results = value; OnPropertyChanged("Results"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler ph = PropertyChanged;
        if (ph != null)
            ph(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: Please clarify what your actual questions is. As it is, I can't tell.

Comment: You need a return type on the `RemoteComputerVM()` method.  Seeing as you return `RST` which is of type `StringBuilder`, you need the return type of `RemoteComputerVM()` to be `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You use binding to do this, you need to set the binding source on the list box. The views DataContext property should be the viewmodel, then your bindings in the view tell the view which bits of the viewmodel to connect to the view. Look at databinding in WPF.

Comment: Also, you're mixing up the public property / private backing field naming convention.  The convention is to have the lower case first letter on the name of backing field, and uppercase first letter on the public property name.

Comment: As a starter, what do you actually want to show in the list box? You know, a list box shows a list/collections of whatever items. But i can't see no list/collection of anything in your code. Show me in your code where you create/declare that list/collection of items you want to put in the list box...

Comment: @Sudsy1002 I'm trying to get the WMI results to show in the listbox I have in XAML view

Comment: @elgonzo before I started the MVVM part, I had it showing up directly in the listbox. Long story short, I was using a StringBuilder to gather all the info and then I was planning to show it on the listbox. I'm assuming its a bad approach?

Comment: @Charleh I tried the <window.resources> to bind the source but autosense doesn't even recognize any code in the ViewModel.

Comment: @Oystein I think that's where I'm getting confused. Can you please show me a code example?

Comment: @Besiktas, ask yourself: Is a StringBuilder a collection/list?

Comment: @Besiktas See my answer.

Comment: @Oystein, how does that help with the listbox problem? If you are so eager to direct attention to your answer, make at least sure it makes a lick of sense with regard to the question/problem...

Comment: @elgonzo See his comments in the code examples in his question, and you'll see it's related.

Comment: @Oystein, his real problem is to get the information he wants to display in his GUI to be displayed in his GUI. Your "answer" really doesn't address that elephant in the room, neither does it even try acknowledging the utter disconnect between StringBuilder and ListBox. which points rather towards a "confusion problem" than a "technical" programming problem...

Comment: @elgonzo Seeing as it won't even build before addressing the return type of `RemoteComputerVM()` method, and any attempts to set the incorrectly named `_results` public property will get it stuck in a loop, I think that's a good place to start.  But hey, please add a better answer.

Comment: @Oystein I know Stringbuilder isn't a collection/list. I actually started this with a textbox. I know it doesn't help with the question. But thats where does the confusion is coming from. At this point I'm just trying to get something out as result.

Comment: @Oystein, as i said in my comment before, it is a confusion problem, not a programming problem. Also, did you notice there is another answer already that actually tried to to actually address the problem (not by me, btw). Yeah, sure, whatever you say...

Comment: @Besiktas, then start by articulating what precisely you want to display in the listbox. I.e., what are the items ("lines") supposed to be? Each item a different computer with its associated information? Or should the listbox just show information about one computer, with each item/line being one piece of information about that computer? (The foreach loop in your code make me think the former, but i am not sure)

Comment: @elgonzo I'm just trying to get the WMI info from the remote computer to show on the list box. Something like  
BuildNumber     : 0000
RegisteredUser  : UserName
SerialNumber    : 0000-00000-00000-XXXXX
Version         : 10.0.0000   On each line

Comment: Do you mean `BuildNumber : 0000 RegisteredUser : UserName SerialNumber : 0000-00000-00000-XXXXX Version : 10.0.0000` as one item/line in the listbox? An multiple such lines for different computers?

Comment: yes exactly. Also, it really doesn't have to be a listbox as long as the format is readable aligned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166423/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-besiktas).

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the simplest example to get started, should be self-explanative:**

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Model}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Model />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding UpdateText}"
            Content="Update text" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    internal class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _collection;

        public Model()
        {
            UpdateText = new RelayCommand(UpdateTextExecute);
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        public RelayCommand UpdateText { get; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
        {
            get => _collection;
            set
            {
                _collection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void UpdateTextExecute(object s)
        {
            var text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Collection.Add(text);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Command:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, s => true)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now go and check the documentation on things you don't understand.